# Flexible DIV keeping aspect ratio, but how to have max height?

Tags: css

Using the padding trick to have an element scale in a responsive manner and maintain a set aspect ratio. But how do you set a max-height when the height is coming from padding?

See example, I would like this to scale but once it's hits a set height then the height does not scale (but retains full width).

```
#container {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #ccc;
    padding-top: 23%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/louiswalch/9h4c8tor/

Comment: set a max-width since widt is the reference for height. http://jsfiddle.net/9h4c8tor/13/  use a pseudo and will allow to grow if content big, stands in the flow ....

Answer (score 4):

If your container needs to be the full page width, like in your fiddle, you can use `height: 23vw` instead of `padding: 23%`. By doing so, you can also set a max height:

```css
#container {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #ccc;
    height: 23vw;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#container .inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="inner">This div should scale with the browser, and maintain the same aspect ratio.</div>
</div>
```

Of course, if the element is less wide, but you know the formula, you can adjust the width. For instance, if you want it to be 50% of the page width, you can make the height: `calc(23vw * 0.5)`, or just `11.5vw`.

PS: If you want to position the inner element inside the outer, make sure to add `position: relative` to the outer element. This will make the top, left, right and bottom of the inner element relative to the boundaries of the outer element.

Comment: Hmm, nice option but something more supported.

Comment: More supported? This is supported in major browser, including IE9 and up: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units Noe IE8, that's right, but maybe it's acceptable to use this for IE9, and let IE8 and lower have a slighty less responsive banner.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot limit the height independently of the width using the padding trick. However, you can fake it.

You can figure out what the width will be at the height that you want to limit the element to, then wrap the element in a container and set the max-width of that container to the specified width and center it.

Then to allow the background to continue across, wrap the container and apply the background color to the wrapper.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9h4c8tor/14/))

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.wrp-bg {
    background-color: #666;
}
.wrp {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#container {
    padding-top: 23%;
    position: relative;
}
#container .inner {
    color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 11px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrp-bg">
    <div class="wrp">
        <div id="container">
            <div class="inner">This div should scale with the browser, and maintain the same aspect ratio.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```